# send array in post method

Tags: http, ionic-framework

i would like to know how to post an array in post method using ionic 3

```
Array : any=[]; 
this.http.post('myurl',JSON.stringify(arry));
```

doesn't work

Error :

[image]

Comment: Can you please share more detail how you are creating array with value and how you are passing that into post method ?

Comment: this.db.list<MoniteurModel>('/Moniteurs').valueChanges().subscribe(info =>{
     for(var i =0 ; i<info.length ; i++)
     {
     this.Moniteur=info[i]; 
     console.log('Adresse IP : ', this.Moniteur.IP); 
     this.AdresseIP.push(this.Moniteur.IP); 
    
     }
    
     
   });
and to I want to send the This.Moniteur array in post Method

Comment: Please add it in your question it will be more clear and readable.